# how can i upload/download images into GAE datastore?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-datastore

(android-studio/java)
Hi, i want to develop an application, where users can upload images etc. I already worked with GAE datastore, so I know how you store entities and stuff, but how is this working with images ?

Comment: If you want to use datastore then [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/java/serving_dynamic_images) will help  otherwise I would prefer go for blob store or Google Cloud Storage for objects like images or video.just for info GAE also provide [image service] (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images) to manipulate image data in your App.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you images are below the 1MB limit datastore is not recommended. You should store images either using the [Blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), both are optimized for binary files and will work better than the datastore with benefits like the [Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/) and dedicated serving (images are hosted and served without consuming your frontend hours).